# Angular ui-router Nested states open from url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm try to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage nested views on a single page app.

Let's say I want to create a dashboard application with a common area and multiple views.

The main and the nested states are handled like this:

```
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: 'MY HOME PAGE'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/pages/login.html'
    })
    .state('registration', {
        url: '/registration',
        templateUrl: '/pages/registration.html'
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html' 
    })
    .state('dashboard.me', {
        url: '/me',
        templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/me.html'
    })
    .state('dashboard.messages', {
        url: '/messages',
        templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/messages.html'
    })
    .state('dashboard.friends', {
        url: '/friends',
        templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/friends.html'
    });
```

The dashboard HTML page is the following:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl" ng-init="init()">

<h2>DASHBOARD</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.me">Me</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.messages">My Messages</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.friends">My Friends</a></li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>
```

The above HTML is also included inside an *ui-view*.

Everything works fine if I navigate my application using the anchors.
By the way if I try to go directly to ***myhost/dashboard/me*** or ***myhost/dashboard/friends*** (every path with two levels of nested views) the app doesn't work. I get an angular (unexpected token <) but I don't think it's relevant...

It seems like it's not able to resolve the first level of nested view.
The following images show the HTML obtained when the navigation is done using anchors: [image: When I navigate using anchors]

and the HTML obtained when the page is called directly from the browser address link:

[image: When I call directly the page from the browser]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You might be missing `#` in your URL. Try something `host/#/dashboard/me`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that angular is not loading, hence the error. The code looks correct to me though, unless you missed the closing tag for

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl" ng-init="init()">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript State Configurations :

```
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: 'MY HOME PAGE'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '/pages/login.html'
    })
    .state('registration', {
        url: '/registration',
        templateUrl: '/pages/registration.html'
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        abstract: true,
        parent: 'home',
        templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html'
    })
    .state('dashboard.me', {
        url: '/me',
        views: {
            '@dashboard_view': {
                templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/me.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('dashboard.messages', {
        url: '/messages',
        views: {
            '@dashboard_view': {
                templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/messages.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('dashboard.friends', {
        url: '/friends',
        views: {
            '@dashboard_view': {
                templateUrl: '/pages/dashboard/friends.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

Dashboard HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl" ng-init="init()">


<h2>DASHBOARD</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.me">Me</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.messages">My Messages</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.friends">My Friends</a></li>
</ul>

<div ui-view="dashboard_view"></div>
```

You can get more details:

[Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

[Nested States and Nested Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)

Comment: Thanks for your Mohan.
I don't think it works this way. If I set the state ***dashboard*** as abstract it is no longer available actually.
It is also impossible to reach the ***/dashboard/me*** neither using the anchors nor by url.

Comment: @cq5beginner This is best practice to work with nested view. If we are rendering the view in ui-view in main template then there is no use of ui routes. I can help you on this if you still have an issue i can create a demo app for you. I just want you to implement ui route properly.

Comment: It would be very useful a little demo actually :) In the mean time I'll try to investigate more